# setting up two Django websites under Apache with WSGI

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I've set up a django website as described in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

Now I want to setup another version of the site (different source dir, different database) to run on the same server. There are active users and flex apps who use app #1, so I want to keep app #1 access unchanged. I also rather not change the urls.py at all even for app #2.

I was thinking of different port for app #2

For example
http://192.168.1.1/load_book/123/       will load book from app #1
http://192.168.1.1:444/load_book/123/   will load book from app #2

I'm a complete noob to Apache and WSGI...  how do I set it up?

Comment: Why do the websites have different code, different databases but the same URLs?

Comment: its actually two versions of the same web app...

Comment: Can you clarify whether you expect each site to appear to be at the root of the web site or whether it is okay to be mounted at a sub URL. Note as pointed out below, mounting at a sub URL does not mean that urls.py needs to be changed, nor your templates, so long as you have used correct coding techniques in templates to construct href URLs to other parts of the same site.

Comment: clarification:  I want to keep access to site1 unmodified, that is at the root (to avoid changing existing links, bookmarks etc). I'm willing to accept changes to path for site2, but only if doesn't break the code base. Modification to wsgi script or settings.py is of course fine. 
I'm afraid in our code we use all over the place access to urls assuming it starts from the root (eg. Redirect to "/accounts/login" or to "/"), and I'm worried this will break when the app is mounted at a sub URL.

Comment: Then you should be using the 'url' template tag and other ways of generating reverse URLs rather than hardcoding URL paths in templates and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attatch the wsgi application to different sub-paths under the same domain. If you do this the paths to the views inside Django will still be the same. You do not have to modify the urls.py. In the following example Django will regard `/site1` as the root of `project1`.

Check out http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationInstructions for documentation on mod_wsgi.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess example
    WSGIProcessGroup example
    WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /home/django/project1/deploy/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/django/project1/deploy>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /site2 /home/django/project2/deploy/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/django/project2/deploy>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now the two sites will run in the same daemon process using different python sub-interpreters.

Comment: thank you nfg,
I tried to set it up with a small change that the alias to site1 is "/" and the alias to site2 is "/site2" because I want site1 access to remain unmodified. Now access to site1 works, but access to /site2 doesn't work as expected - it runs the site1 code with site1 urls and database (settings.py).  Any ideas how to debug it?

Comment: That shouldn't happen unless you have stuffed around and set WSGIApplicationGroup the same for each instance when you shouldn't. Suggest you create two daemon process groups and delegate each Django instance to a separate daemon process group. That way they can't interfere with each other in memory even if you do set WSGIApplicationGroup the same. You should post your actual Apache configuration related to the mounting of the application, like example in this answer so can see what you have done.

Comment: If you place `WSGIScriptAlias / /project1` before `WSGIScriptAlias /site2 /project2` all the requests will go to project1. It is in the order of first appearance. You can place the project2 declaration before the project1 declaration, but then none of the URL's inside project1 should start with `/site2`.

Comment: Thanks @nfg for pointing that out. Even if using separate daemon processes if ordering wasn't right then it wouldn't have made a difference.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by they have the same URLs? The same hostname, perhaps?

Let's say you've got 2 apps:

- http://example.com/your_app
- http://example.com/my_app

These can both be Django apps, served by WSGI, on the same Apache instance. Using either `Directory` or `Location` directives in your apache conf to specify the `.wsgi` loader file as described in the django docs linked above:

```
<Location /your_app>
    WSGIScriptAlias /your_app /path/to/mysite/apache/your_app/django.wsgi
    ...
</Location>
<Location /my_app>
    WSGIScriptAlias /my_app /path/to/mysite/apache/my_app/django.wsgi
    ...
</Location>
```

The only real gotcha is that you'll need to tell `your_app` and `my_app` that they are no longer on the document root of the host. To do this, add a `base_url` parameter to your `settings.py` and prefix all of the entries in your `urls.py` with this param. This will ensure when the request comes through Apache, your python app can route it accordingly.

For an easy example of how this is done, have a look at the code for [Bookworm](http://code.google.com/p/threepress/source/browse/trunk/bookworm/), a Django app.

Comment: Sorry, your example is wrong. WSGIScriptAlias cannot be placed inside of Location or Directory directives, it should be at top scope in VirtualHost. Just get rid of the Location directive containers and leave WSGIScriptAlias behind, or move the WSGIScriptAlias outside of Location, although at that point would question what you think does goes inside of the Location.

Comment: Plus, there's no need to set anything in settings for the base URL - WSGI passes this through via the `SCRIPT_NAME` header, which Django takes into account when reversing URLs.

Comment: Thank you smcphill, Graham and Daniel.
I should have mentioned in my question I don't want to modify the urls.py and I want to keep the same path to views. This is why I was thinking of different port or different subdomain to choose between the two versions.  I'll change my question to reflect this point.